# Does passing delegates to static classes cause leaks?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, static, delegates

Working in .Net 2.0, moving the code base to 4.0 soon

Recently I have been working with serializing classes with events, and finding my event subscribers (i.e. a Form) would attempt to serialize too (I am using [field:NonSerializable] now to stop this).

This got me to thinking, if I pass a delegate to a static class's method (to be used method scope only), does the static class root the delegate's owner, causing it to be uncollectable by GC?

I have a static ListUtilities class doing the job of lambda expressions, as well as static caches, that I regularly pass delegates, and wondering if this could be leaking memory?

Comment: Given that LINQ is built on top of extension methods, which are syntactic sugar for static methods, do you not think this would be a *massive* issue for anyone using LINQ if it were so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, nothing to worry about there. Passing a delegate to a method is fine, (unless that method stores the delegate somewhere indefinitely).

What *is* problematic, though is static events (or events on long-lived objects, such as singletons). If you don't unsubscribe those, then the event can keep the object alive forever. For example:

```
// this object is meant to be short-lived
var obj = new SomeType();

// some static event
MyUtility.SomeEvent += { obj.Foo(); };
```

now the static event on `MyUtility` prevents the new `SomeType` instance from being collected until that event subscription is removed... which it probably never will be, since it is an anonymous method (which need voodoo to unsubscribe).

Comment: Thanks Marc, thinking through this further, I guessed that once the stack frame containing the delegate was popped off the stack, there would be nowhere for the calling object to be rooted to on the static object. Thanks for the confirmation, anyway. Have an upvote and a tick.

Comment: @johnc indeed, in most use it is the *stack* that has the reference, which is transient. It only becomes a problem when the reference gets put onto something that isn't ever collected (like: a static/singleton event)

Answer (score 3):

This won't cause memory leaks. As long as you don't save the delegate reference in a static variable, then after the method has finished the delegate owner can be collected.